# Realtime html 5 application polling

Tags: android, web-services, html, polling

Finally after a while I have an application that pushes notifications to android and iphone.

Now what is the best way for me to retrieve notifications from a webservice. I dont like the idea of polling every 5min. Is there another way for me to push the notifications to the handset from the server or some optimised polling method?

Thanks
I am a newbie so go easy on me.

Comment: Have you looked at http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/

Comment: Thanks this looks interesting. I will take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made use of nodejs as my server and websockets. This seems to work very nicely.